# Grep from array is much slower than grep from file

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

In an attempt to optimise my bash script I loaded my file into an array and tried to grep from there, and I notice that this grep from memory is much, much slower than a standard grep from file, even taking into account the fact that the disk I/O is taking out of the equation.

1) OK so I have a large file (about 3000 lines) with name=value pairs, this is my "cache". I load it into an array from file (straight-forward enough)

```
# load to array
l_i_array_index=1
while read line
  do
  g_a_cache[$l_i_array_index]=$line
  let "l_i_array_index += 1"
  done < $g_f_cache
```

2) Then I run a little benchmark for the search performance:

```
time for i in `seq 1 100`
  do
  for l_i_array_index in `seq 1 ${#g_a_cache[@]}`
    do
      echo ${g_a_cache[$l_i_array_index]}
    done | grep -c $l_s_search_string > /dev/null
  done

real    0m14.387s
user    0m13.846s
sys     0m1.781s
```

3) The same, but directly from disk file:

```
time for i in `seq 1 100`
  do
  grep -c $l_s_search_string $g_f_cache > /dev/null
  done
real    0m0.347s
user    0m0.161s
sys     0m0.136s
```

So performance is 13 to 40 times worse, when it should be better.

**My question is: 1)** what is the reason for this strange behaviour **2)** is this solvable within bash or should I bite the bullet and finally redo it in Python

P.S. The test is done on Mac (bash v4), in Cygwin, time per ONE search is over a second with normal grep (which is faster), and over 10s with the array method. The script is close to unusable..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `grep` program has been heavily optimized over many, many years by top experts in the field of searching and algorithm design. You're simply not going to beat it with a shell script. That's an absurd notion.

I honestly can't imagine why you would expect to be anywhere near as fast as `grep`. Perhaps you're thinking that all of `grep`s disk I/O actually requires doing something to the actual physical disk. But that's not so. Every modern operating system has a disk cache, and the file will be in the cache after the first time it's read, which takes a tiny fraction of a second.

Comment: David, I suspected as much :) I still have a problem with optimising the search for Cygwin, which takes over a second per search. Any hope for me there? Thanks!

Comment: That's strange. I wonder if it's process startup time. Run a test, launch `grep` but have it do basically nothing at all (maybe search a file that doesn't exist so you just get an error) and see how long that takes.

Comment: David, grep is pretty fast on Mac, it's Cygwin which is giving me problems. Do you think there would be a way to speed up ONE random search?

Comment: Not without knowing why it's slow, hence the test I suggested.

Comment: Sorry, got it. You do have a point: "grep x x" executes in 0.4s or less on Mac and 1 to 4 sec on Cygwin :(

Comment: So it's Cygwin's process startup (fork) overhead. Unfortunately, UNIXes are based around `fork` being cheap and simple, and it's just *not* on Windows. There are some ways to make it a bit faster (disabling shell completion, minimizing PATH, and so on), but it's inherently expensive due to the mismatch of UNIX and Windows design.

Answer (score 1):

This might have something to do with filesystem caches, which causes "optimized" implementation to actually add overhead.

Filesystem caches can be observed in following:

```
localhost elhigu$ time grep -r "testnottofind" * 
real    0m22.468s
user    0m0.172s
sys 0m0.828s
localhost elhigu$ time grep -r "testnottofind" * 
real    0m0.826s
user    0m0.087s
sys 0m0.232s
localhost elhigu$ time grep -r "testnottofind2" * 
real    0m0.285s
user    0m0.084s
sys 0m0.190s
localhost elhigu$ time grep -r "moretesting" * 
real    0m0.285s
user    0m0.086s
sys 0m0.185s
localhost elhigu$
```

there is more info https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8914/does-grep-use-a-cache-to-speed-up-the-searches.

Comment: Mikael, perhaps I didn't pose the question well. I do not actually use subsequent searches. My real problem is that I have to speed up normal "grep $string $file" searches, and arrays doesn't seem to be the way. Esp in Cygwin the search performance is really bad, over 1s per search. For an interactive script that's atrocious.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that grep is too slow on Cygwin. Have you tried if the http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ port works faster?

Comment: Cygwin was my knee-jerk reaction, I'll try unixutils too, thanks!